# Keep rotating Virtual Desktop by Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

I want Virtual Desktops to keep rotating if they hit an end. Suppose if there are 5 virtual desktop 1-5, pressing Win+Tab stop working as soon it reaches 5th virtual desktop. I want it to repeat its sequence again from 1 as Alt+Tab do.

How can I do this?

Comment: @Ramhound I can do this with an AHK script but it will be complex and bit hackish. I posted this here hoping somebody know of some registry trick or something.

Comment: I found a way to do it (using an AHK DLL library). I can post link later if anybody else needs it too.

Comment: could please post the link with instruction for rotating virtual desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a library you can use with AHK to have infinite rotations of virtual desktop in either direction.

https://github.com/Ciantic/VirtualDesktopAccessor

They have many examples too in readme.